# Converting datapoint to integer python

Tags: python, sign, led

I have an LED sign that I am sending weather data too, but ran across a problem with temperature, which reads out in decimals which I believe the sign will not read, I get this error.

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pyledsign/minisign.py", line 276, in processtags
data=data.replace('<f:normal>',str(normal,'latin-1'))
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Here is my code below for the sign. The error is brought when sending this to the sign.

```
 mysign.queuemsg(data=current_weather.temperature, speed=2).
```

So I was wondering how I could state that weather temperature would always read as an int. putting int() around it does not work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import datetime
import forecastio
from pyledsign.minisign import MiniSign

def main():
    """
    Run load_forecast() with the given lat, lng, and time arguments.
    """

    api_key = 'my api key'

    lat = 42.3314
    lng = -83.0458

    forecast = forecastio.load_forecast(api_key, lat, lng,)

    mysign = MiniSign(devicetype='sign')

    print ("===========Currently Data=========")
    current_weather = forecast.currently()
    print (current_weather.summary)
    print (current_weather.temperature)
    mysign.queuemsg(data=current_weather.summary, speed=2)
    mysign.queuemsg(data=current_weather.temperature, speed=2)
    mysign.sendqueue(device='/dev/ttyUSB0')

    print ("===========Daily Data=========")
    by_day = forecast.daily()
    print ("Daily Summary: %s" %(by_day.summary))
    mysign.queuemsg(data=by_day.summary)
    mysign.sendqueue(device='/dev/ttyUSB0')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It needs to be a string, not a float or integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is from a method that is expecting a string.

You should explicitly convert your numerical values to string before sending them to the sign.

```
mysign.queuemsg(data=str(current_weather.temperature), speed=2)
```

You could also do some additional string operations like concatination.

```
mysign.queuemsg(data=str(current_weather.temperature) + ' degrees', speed=2)
```

You can also use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) to convert the value into a string and control things like the number of decimals. Just be aware that string formatting works differently in Python 2 and Python 3. For example, in Python 2 you could

```
mysign.queuemsg(data='%s degrees' % current_weather.temperature, speed=2)
```

Comment: worked perfect! thank you! I didn't think an str would work before because fro the other command it would read the actual words 'instance data block: '

Comment: @N3VO great! Don't forget to vote and mark the question correct then.

Comment: I had one more question actually, if I wanted to run them together in one message, is that possible? I get: 'non-keyword arg after keyword arg' when I try this mysign.queuemsg(data=current_weather.summary, str(current_weather.temperature),
    speed=2)

Comment: You can do any normal string operations. `str(whatever) + 'some more text'`.